# WordPress Plugin ColorPicker and write in CSS file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i develop my own plugin for the first time. I have come very far, so far it works very well.

What I would like to program this time is a, color picker. This Color Picker, should change the HEX code in my CSS file.

I already have a color picker in my backend, but how can I program a function now, where I say, write this into the CSS file in the classe.

I hope you have understood my problem.  Now you have to save the HEX code somewhere.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wp_add_inline_style` function:

```
function my_styles_method() {
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css');
    $color = get_theme_mod( 'my-custom-color' ); // #FF0000
    $custom_css = "
        .mycolor{
            background: {$color};
        }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
```

Comment: How can I link this to a Color Picker? In the backend there must be the option with color picker and save. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's depends how are you using settings storage: )

Comment: I have a database table :-)